# How to include two links within a Bootstrap 4 list group item

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement two links within each of the list group items in a list group, each displaying a different modal. Here's sample code for one of the list group items.

```
<button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-id="123" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#membership-modal">
    <span class="font-weight-bold">Peter Haworth</span>
    <a class="fa fa-info-circle text-secondary float-right" data-memberid="123"
       data-toggle="modal" data-target="#history-modal"
       data-name="Peter Haworth" style="font-size:20px;"></a><br>
    1 year Individual, expiration 12/31/2023
</button>
```

If the user clicks the main body of the list group item, the membership-modal is displayed as expected.

If the user clicks the info icon, I want the history-modal to display but the membership-modal is displayed. However when I close the membership-modal, the history modal is there behind it so it is being displayed but is hidden by the membership-modal.

How can I prevent the membership-modal from being displayed when the info icon is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the info icon outside of the button. You've both clicked the button and the info icon at the same time, so your issue is expected.

To make sure it's still a `list-group-item` wrap everything inside a div. And position the icon wherever you want. The `div` around the button must be `position: relative` for it to work.

```html
  <div class="list-group">
    <div class="position-relative">
      <a class="fa fa-info-circle text-secondary position-absolute" data-memberid="123" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#history-modal" data-name="Peter Haworth" style="font-size:20px; z-index: 10; top: 10px; right: 10px"></a>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-id="123" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#membership-modal">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">Peter Haworth</span>
        <p>1 year Individual, expiration 12/31/2023</p>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyqjdxst/) example

Comment: Perfect, works exactly as I want. Thanks.